# ITextSharp - include footer on every page but the first and the last

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, footer

Currently building a PDF with ITextSharp in C#. The PDF consists of three "parts", a cover page, a table that can span multiple pages, and a final page. The pages that have the table need to include a header on the first page, and a footer on all pages with it, but the cover page and final page do not.

I build the pages using XMLWorker, but that's not really important. My code for building the pages is as follows:

```
    var htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
    htmlContext.SetTagFactory(iTextSharp.tool.xml.html.Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
    var cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);
    /* cssResolver.AddCssFile(@"style.css", true); */
    cssResolver.AddCssFile(@"style.css", true);
    var pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer)));
    XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
    XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);

    /* write out cover page */
    p.Parse(coverpage);

    /* write out table */
    document.NewPage();
    writer.PageEvent = new PDFFooter();
    p.Parse(header); 
    p.Parse(ContentTable); 

    /* write out end page */
    document.NewPage();
    p.Parse(endPage);
```

The trouble I'm having is determining a way to keep the footer from appearing on the end page. I'm overriding OnEndPage to make the footer. Is there a way to detect the last page of the document (without knowing exactly what number page that'll be), and tell it not to use the override so that no footer is printed out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to know if you're on the last page when `OnEndPage()` is triggered, so you'll have to use a trick. Add a Boolean member-variable to your `PDFFooter` class and set it to `false` by default. Only add a footer when this member-variable is `true`.

To make sure you have a footer for the pages that need one, set the member-variable to `true` after adding the `coverpage` and set it back to false before adding the `endPage`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you be a little more specific as to where the boolean variable goes? Does it get declared within my PDFFooter class? If so, how do I reassign its value outside the class? Sorry, primarily a PHP developer, my C# is rusty, particularly with terminology .

Comment: `PDFFooter` is a class. A class can have member-variables and methods. Add a member-variable (e.g. `showFooter`) and add a method (e.g. `SetShowFooter()`) to change the value of that member-variable from outside that class. Hope this clarifies my answer.